# Invalid hook call with an imported React component

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to import and work with this imported React component: https://github.com/YelyseiLukin/react-files-drag-and-drop#readme

But I am trying to do the "usage" part and when I compile the project the console just sends error messages regarding hook calls:

[image]

This is a simplified version ofwhat I have in the profilePhoto.js:

```
import FilesDragAndDrop from '@yelysei/react-files-drag-and-drop';

function ProfilePhoto() {

  
  return (
<FilesDragAndDrop
    onUpload={(files) => console.log(files)}
    count={3}
    formats={['jpg', 'png', 'svg']}
    containerStyles={{
        width: '200px',
        height: '200px',
        border: '1px solid #cccccc',
    }}
    openDialogOnClick
>
    <div style={{
        display: 'flex',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    }}>
        Drop files here
    </div>
</FilesDragAndDrop>
  )
}
export default ProfilePhoto;
```

This is the FilesDragAndDrop.js that is created once I make the "npm i @yelysei/react-files-drag-and-drop"

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

import '../../scss/components/Common/FilesDragAndDrop.scss';

export default function FilesDragAndDrop({onUpload}) {
  return (
    <div className='FilesDragAndDrop__area'>
      Hey, drop me some files
      <span
        role='img'
        aria-label='emoji'
        className='area__icon'
      >
        &#128526;
      </span>
    </div>
  );
}

FilesDragAndDrop.propTypes = {
  onUpload: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};
```

Comment: this is your full code? there is nothing wrong. also why you don't use https://github.com/react-dropzone/react-dropzone?

Comment: Added the code to a separate project and there are no errors. The problem is that when I drag and drop a picture, it doesn't show. I wanted to create this drag and drop without using dropzone just as a challenge